# Many to Many Field Takes all Users Not Chosen Ones

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm trying to prevent users from multiple votes. So I wanna add users to ManyToManyField of the Question object. But when I go to admin all users are added to the field not the voted ones. Here is my Model's code

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    choice_number = models.IntegerField(default=2)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="comparison")
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    
    def subscribe(cls, current_user, new_vote):
        new_vote.users.add(current_user)
```

And here is the function for add users to questions in views.py :

```
def change_vote(request, instruction, pk):
    question = Question.objects.get(pk=pk)
    Question.subscribe(request.user, question)
```

Comment: why dont you just use: `question.users.add(request.user)` ? I am unable to understand what bug could be

Comment: Actually the problem is not on the adding part. When I just make the model without the subscribe function it still adds all the users. I want ManyToManyField to go blank initially but it takes all the users :(

Comment: Have you checked in django shell?

Comment: No and actually I dont know how :/

Comment: `python manage.py shell` then import the models and check their contents to verify

Comment: >>> q =  Question.objects.get(id=1)                                    >>> q.users
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward
.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x00000068B8653108>

Comment: It gave sth like that

Comment: `q.users.all()` to get all users linked with that `q`

Comment: I got it thanks you

Comment: please consider upvoting the solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `question.users.all()` to get `users` related to the `question`